# Scroll content with open drop-down menu

Tags: javascript, html, css, drop-down-menu, scroll

How to scroll the content (with mouse wheel) at the same time when drop-down menu is opened?

The example is in this page (don't pay attention to design, please):

http://www.barcino.travel/

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

**I have checked link give by you-(above)**

- It's nothing any special effect - But, they used just `sticky` Menu with `Scrollable` `Div`.
- For More information you can visit below link:

  1. [sticky Menu - JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/chintansoni/h9757xLq/1/)

     OR
  2. [Stick-to-top Navigation](http://www.backslash.gr/demos/jquery-sticky-navigation/)